# Responsive/Javascript bootstrap conflict on desktop Chrome & Firefox browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

For some reason my website only renders properly on mobile devices?http://www.brandsondigital.com is built using a wordpress theme named beatrix http://simpleqode.com/preview/beatrix/1.0.1/default/index.html - using bootstrap and other scripts. It now doesn't render properly on desktops - fine on mobile devices?  Any idea of where the conflict is that is causing this and how to resolve?

p.s It was fine in browsers desktop and mobile until the beginning of this week (firefox gave in months earlier but it was bearable). The placement of the content is knocked out of position on chrome and firefox but not safari. Lifting the bottom content to the top of the page and not showing the full page content.

Comment: works for me in chrome

Comment: Yup seems to work in chrome, maybe you need to refresh your JS or something, try deleting temp files, and doing a cntrl+F5 in browser?

Comment: Good to hear but this is what i see on the page - the gold block should be at the bottom as a comments section. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1uvSa4Hpk9RM2U5c2FRVG5jbGM/view?usp=sharing - Also the footer cuts off the content before the page finishes https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1uvSa4Hpk9RTVRvaDczX1pmdXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JohnKennedy I am not seeing that in chrome at all, something in cache may be messed up for you? If you delete history, cookies, temp files etc, and then cntrl+F5 on your site in chrome does that help?

Comment: Actually maybe the description isnt super clear? I am seeing the issue on http://www.brandsondigital.com but not on  http://simpleqode.com/preview/beatrix/1.0.1/default/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is margin collapse

Try to add `overflow:hidden;` and `clear:both` on `.section`

Comment: Thanks Stanley - this was the answer that solved my problem. You sir, are a hero.